# git log throws error "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile"

Tags: git, cygwin

I'm learning how to use git by reading [this book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History). However, when I tried to run the `git log` command, I got the following error message :

> 5 [main] less 3928 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to less.exe.stackdump

The numbers 5 and 3928 change every time I try running the command. I'm using the version 2.1.14.1 of Git (64bits) on Windows 10 and I'm executing the command from a cmd console (same problem arises when using PowerShell or Git cmd).

Note : the command `git diff` generates the same error message.

To try out the log command, I've simply edited a "mytestfile.txt" and added two lines of random text, then I've commited by running the command `git commit -a -m my "first commit"`. And then I tried running the log command with no success.

Comment: have you tried from mintty ?

Comment: Same error:( I will try to de-install and re-install git see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `TERM` variable to `xterm` or `xterm-256color`. If you want to leave `TERM` how you have it now, try aliasing `git` to `TERM=xterm-256color git`. This fixed it for me with Git 2.16.1 on Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: Setting the Terminal->Type to "xterm-256color" solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your commit has been made successfully and pushed into the server(?). Then you should be in the project's directory to run the `git log` command.

Note: When you use `git commit` with `-m` the message should be within double quotes.

Comment: The commit has been made successfully but not pushed (I've just tried pushing it (it was succesful) but same log error happens…Even though I think, from what I've understood so far, that pushing is not required in order to see the logs). I'm in the project directory when running the command. Indeed. in my shell, I wrote the commit command with a message within quotation marks. Just forgot to append them here, will edit my question. So yeah, the error's still there…

Comment: I'd suggest to revert the commit and do it again. (git reset --hard <branchNameHere>) If it doesnt work too, I'm afraid I cannot help with your problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in windows and found that in my system path there are reference to two directories which contains git.exe file. 
Like

c:\progra~1\Git\cmd

c:\progra~1\Git\mingw64\bin

I think git by default uses the git.exe which is under Mingw64 directory. So from the system path I removed **c:\progra~1\Git\cmd**.

Now the git log works just fine as before.

Comment: Just to update : How did I find there there are two git.exe ?  I did 
> whereis git

and it showed two git references. From there I caught.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped me. My workaround was to run git inside a Docker container so that I could run the commands I wanted to run.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y git vim && git config --global user.name 'My Name Here' && git config --global user.email 'my.email.here@example.com' && git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

```
$ docker build . -t my-temp-git-container:latest
```

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v "/$(pwd)"://mapped -w //mapped my-temp-git-container bash
# git commit --amend
```